# Is $t=0$ a stationary point?

Tags: calculus

I have a parametric equation 
$$
t^2 \textbf{i} + (t^3 +1) \textbf{j} =0
$$
So to find stationary point is to differentiate so I did and got 
$$
2t \textbf{i} + 3t^2\textbf{j} 
$$
Then equate to zero. Now my question is I know for sure one of the stationary points is $-2/3$ but is $0$ a stationary point too? Why or why not?

That's because when I plotted the graph out using $-4 < t < 4$, the stationary points don't make sense at all (it's not the max or min)... Can someone please try it out and see if it's something I did wrong? Thank you!!!

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference

Comment: I did this for free..but take Timbuc's link and read :).

Comment: @Chinny84 thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A stationnary point depend only on the parametrisation of your graph. You could have the same graph, but with a different parametrisation, and different stationnary point.

Imagine your equation describe the movement of a mobile in respect to time. You can make the same graph, but going at different speeds or even stopping.

These stopping points are called "stationnary points"

Comment: isn't stationary point the maximum or minimum?

Comment: @LucasCK not persé when working with parametrics. If both partial derivatives are zero, different books use different terminology.

Comment: @imranfat got it!! thanks!